# compatible Video Player for mobile and system browser

Tags: video

I am working on a social networking website that should be opened from every browser in desktop or laptop system, as well as it's mobile website is also going to be viewed from every mobile browser.

When user uploads video , video is compressed and saved in .mp4 format , with a snap image.

I want to know that **which player will best suitable for all (desktop/laptop) browsers and for  mobile website .**
On internet I found   , but both have it's limitation.

I have read somewhere, that save video's different format like mp4, flv etc ,and as per browser compatibility play that format. But i don't think so it's a good solution because saving different format will take unnecessary space.

Any other options suggested will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlowPlayer (http://flowplayer.org/) or jwplayer (http://www.jwplayer.com/) do work well in both your scenarios.

Comment: Are they cost free? and support both mobile browsers and system browsers (i.e -6,7,8, google chrome, mozilla, safari). Is they support .mp4 format. From where I can get there playing code.

Comment: @user3119503, yes its free, and can play on all the devices. Here is a link describing with the code. 

http://www.alynnlee.com:9996/KB/a21/getting-flowplayer-to-play-on-all-browsers-android.aspx

Comment: Thanks For Replying, In your posted link there is Key might be for commercial package. But I am using free version , for that what the keys will be. I have downloaded free version flow player from it's site, is this the same thing that you have given me by link or something another. My video's are saved in side a folder like www.xyz.com/video and are called from database by path.

Comment: I will surely add your post as answer. When my posted question is cleared.